# Connect a computer to the same printer via a direct USB connection and a network connection simultaneously?

Tags: usb, printer, network-printer

Can I connect a computer to the same printer via a direct USB connection and a network connection simultaneously?

The idea behind is that while I work from home and am connected to my work via VPN, [I cannot access the printer via home network](https://superuser.com/q/897024/282786). However, I still want to be able to connect to the printer via network when I am not connected to the VPN (and in this case I prefer using the printer as a network printer and not as a USB printer).

Comment: You will just have two copies of the same printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, plug it in!

Assuming it's already hooked up via network, wait until Windows detects the new printer port, and installs the new queue. Go to the **Start Menu**, and open up **Devices and Printers**. Then right-click on the printer, select **Printer Properties** (not just *Properties*).

Click on the **Ports** tab, and tick the box for **printer pooling**. This allows you to select both ports, the TCP/IP port and the USB001 port (or whatever one is currently used). Save your settings. Windows will print to whatever port is available.

Failing this, you can also *pause* printing until you disconnect from the VPN. Advantages include not seeing error messages about finding the printer, and the queuing happens almost instantaneously. Disadvantages include not seeing error messages right away (i.e. paper out, but that's easy enough to fix), and remembering to Resume printing.

Answer (score 2):

You will find that no printer manufacturer will say that they support this configuration.  However, in every case that I've tried it, it works just fine.

Alternatively, you can look at using split tunneling, which would allow you to use your local network printer while connected to a VPN.

Comment: I've never tried exactly this but I've done USB + Parallel.  No promises as to what happens if you print by both methods at the same time but otherwise it behaved fine.

Answer (score -2):

I am a Homeworker and came across the same problem. My printer is able to be set up on the Home Network as a Wireless printer - which is what I have done. Of course it is then not accessible to my Works Laptop when on the VPN - so I simply connect it to my Works Laptop directly via USB cable. I can now access it from Home Machines or Works Machine at all times.